# grunt installation error in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grunt

I tried to install grunt using npm, which errors out, without giving me much detail into the reasoning.. reproducing the log here.

```
npm -v
1.1.4

sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: grunt-cli
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:156:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1256:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/raghav/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-47-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /home/raghav
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: grunt-cli
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/raghav/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Tried to confirm if the server i actually accessible, and here it is -

```
ping registry.npmjs.org
PING a.sni.fastly.net (103.245.222.162) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 103.245.222.162: icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=243 ms
```

Comment: I just tested on my 13.10 using npm version 1.2.18 and it installed without any problems. Perhaps you should try upgrading either the system or `npm`.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the contents of `/home/raghav/npm-debug.log`?

Comment: Are you working behind a proxy? I am working behind a proxy and I am facing the same problem.

Comment: No i m not behind any proxy.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/installing-from-npm-fails

The second answer did the job for me

Answer (score 5):

As @geon noted over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22558226/edit):

I used apt-get to install node. Npm was not included in that package, so it had to be installed separately. I assumed that would work, but apparently the npm version in the Ubuntu distribution was outdated.

The node [wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) has this instruction:

Obtaining a recent version of Node or installing on older Ubuntu and other apt-based distributions may require a few extra steps. Example install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

After that, npm was already included and worked perfectly.